# Looking for easiest way to perform average of common dictionaries in a list

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have a list of dictionaries like,

```
list1 = [{'a':[10,2],'b':[20,4]}, {'a':[60,6],'b':[40,8]}]
```

Trying to get the final output as

```
list1 = [{'a':[35,4],'b':[30,6]}]
```

I was trying to get the list of values for each key in each dictionary and average them based on the length of the list and put into a new dictionary.

Not sure of the best / most pythonic way of doing this.

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to do this. A simple one iterates over each key, over each inner index, and calculates the average to store to a new dictionary:

```
from pprint import pprint

list1 = [
    {'a': [10, 2], 'b': [20, 4]},
    {'a': [60, 6], 'b': [40, 8]},
]

means = {}

for key in list1[0]:
    key_means = []
    means[key] = key_means
    for index in range(len(list1[0][key])):
        key_means.append(
            sum(
                ab_dict[key][index]
                for ab_dict in list1
            ) / len(list1)
        )

pprint(means)
```

This implementation assumes that keys appearing in the first row are uniformly represented in all other rows.